# ElasticsearchParseException: malformed, expected settings to start with 'object', instead was [VALUE_STRING]

Tags: elasticsearch

I got following exception while starting elastic search server

```
Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.common.settings.SettingsException: Failed to load settings from [file:/usr/local/elasticsearch-1.7.1/config/elasticsearch.yml]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromStream(ImmutableSettings.java:985)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromUrl(ImmutableSettings.java:969)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalSettingsPreparer.prepareSettings(InternalSettingsPreparer.java:95)
        at org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginManager.main(PluginManager.java:396)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchParseException: malformed, expected settings to start with 'object', instead was [VALUE_STRING]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.loader.XContentSettingsLoader.load(XContentSettingsLoader.java:66)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.loader.XContentSettingsLoader.load(XContentSettingsLoader.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.loader.YamlSettingsLoader.load(YamlSettingsLoader.java:46)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.ImmutableSettings$Builder.loadFromStream(ImmutableSettings.java:982)
        ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got the issue.

I had updated config/elasticsearch.yml  for cluster.name and node.name like below

```
cluster.name:my_elastic_cluster  
node.name:"EL1_NODE"
```

> But look like parser doesn't like this format. Its need spaces with
>   **":"** delimiter

I added one space before and after **:** and it worked !!!

```
> cluster.name : my_elastic_cluster  
> node.name : "EL1_NODE"
```

Comment: In fact, .yaml files only needs the space after the colon `: `.

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is : Do not put any space before any key. Also define a key value in the yml file is to put a key and then a space, then a colon and then again a space, then value.
e.g.  cluster.name : my_elastic_cluster